# php jwt login storage

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, jwt

I'm building a web app with CodeIgniter 4 where I implemented a REST API for register and login and a profile page just a test my login.

I have a login form that sends a javascript fetch post request to my api and I receives a jwt token. This is working.

Now I am in the situation where I think I did not understand the principle.
I want that the user stays logged in and doesn't need to re-login every time. The token expires after 12h.

And I want to use php (if possible) as the entire app runs on php.

Currently, I have a little javascript function to store my token:

```js
const store = {};
store.setJWT = (data) => {
    this.JWT = data;
};
```

But this is not secure against page reload.

Additionally I am creating a cookie with php, when the user logs in:

```php
helper('cookie');
set_cookie([
    'name' => 'login',
    'value' => $token,
    'expire' => $exp,
    'httponly' => true,
    'secure' => true,
]);
```

I am able to fetch data from the API using the cookie or the `store` object.

```js
const token = getCookie('login');

const res = await fetch('/profile', {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` // or store.JWT
    }
});
```

So.... what I want is:
The user goes to a protected url e.g. `https://myapp.com/profile` and if he is logged in, he has access. If not, he gets redirect to the login page.

Is using the cookie to store the jwt a good idea? Or did I completely misunderstood the idea of JWT and it is not used to be used for a login?

Additionally: I still don't know if biulding the login as an API was the best idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is nothing wrong with building "login with API". It is common practice. And JWT is perfectly suited for auth.

You sure can store JWT token inside a cookie, but it is a little bit wrong in my opinion. Usually JWT tokens are stored in the [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) on the client side. It will persist after page reload.

Set token in the local storage:

```js
localStorage.setItem('token', token);
```

Get token from the local storage:

```js
token = localStorage.getItem('token');
```

To better understand the conception of the JWT you can copy some token (without Bearer) and paste it in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/). Basically JWT contain all the required information about the user and server can trust this information.

And when you set the cookie like this

```php
set_cookie([
    'name' => 'login',
    'value' => $token,
    'expire' => $exp,
    'httponly' => true,
    'secure' => true,
]);
```

It is an overkill. JWT possible already contains all this information and you can extract it from the token.

Comment: I read that local storage is vulnerable and saving the token is not a good idea at all. But without saving it, I don't understand how to use it

Comment: it is vulnerable is someone have an ability to run custom javascript code on your site. at this point the attacker have compete control over your cookies and username/password and nothing can prevent this. or what kind of vulnerability are you talking about?